# How do I retrieve an element along with the list in which it resides from a list of lists?

Tags: r

Suppose, I am having a list of lists like below:

```
> myList
[[1]]
 [1]   0   7  14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70  77  84  91  98 105 112 119 126 133 140 147 154 161 168 175 182 189 196 203 210 217

[[2]]
 [1]   1   8  15  22  29  36  43  50  57  64  71  78  85  92  99 106 113 120 127 134 141 148 155 162 169 176 183 190 197 204 211 218

[[3]]
 [1]   2   9  16  23  30  37  44  51  58  65  72  79  86  93 100 107 114 121 128 135 142 149 156 163 170 177 184 191 198 205 212 219

[[4]]
 [1]   3  10  17  24  31  38  45  52  59  66  73  80  87  94 101 108 115 122 129 136 143 150 157 164 171 178 185 192 199 206 213 220

[[5]]
 [1]   4  11  18  25  32  39  46  53  60  67  74  81  88  95 102 109 116 123 130 137 144 151 158 165 172 179 186 193 200 207 214 221
```

How do I search for an element in this list of lists and retrieve the entire list in which it belongs?

I tried something like below:

```
> myList[grep(7, myList)][[1]]
 [1]   0   7  14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70  77  84  91  98 105 112 119 126 133 140 147 154 161 168 175 182 189 196 203 210 217
```

This case looks correct, but when I tried this for the below case, I got the wrong result.

```
> myList[grep(18, myList)][[1]]
 [1]   0   7  14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70  77  84  91  98 105 112 119 126 133 140 147 154 161 168 175 182 189 196 203 210 217
```

while the correct output should be :

```
[1]   4  11  18  25  32  39  46  53  60  67  74  81  88  95 102 109 116 123 130 137 144 151 158 165 172 179 186 193 200 207 214 221
```

Is there any possible solution to this?

EDIT::
The sample list can be produced using --

```
l <- seq(0, 194)
myList <- list()

for (d in l){
        temp <- intersect(seq(d, max(l), by = 7),l)
        if (any(sapply(myList,function(x) d %in% x)) == FALSE){
            myList <- append(myList, list(temp))
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Could try:

```
myList[sapply(myList, function(x) any(x %in% 7))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `purrr` package:

```
library(purrr)
keep(mylist, function(x, y) {any(x == y)}, y = 18)
```

`purrr` provides many useful list-handling functions which are documented in a cheatsheet that can be found [here](https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/raw/master/purrr.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

If 18 is a number you wish to find in the list, try:

```
myList[sapply(myList, function(x) 18 %in% x)]
```